# Check the list and split the sentence in python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist = ['test copy', 'test project', 'test', 'project']
```

I want to see if my sentence includes the aforementioned `mylist`elements and split the sentence from the first match and obtain its first part.

For example:

```
mystring1 = 'it was a nice test project and I enjoyed it a lot'
```

output should be: `it was a nice`

```
mystring2 = 'the example test was difficult'
```

output should be: `the example`

My current code is as follows.

```
for sentence in L:
    if mylist in sentence:
        splits = sentence.split(mylist)
        sentence= splits[0]
```

However, I get an error saying `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What is L here?

Comment: Are you looking for `if sentence in mylist`?..

Comment: you may be loop in your mylist rather than sentence and you can split your whole sentence according to every word in list. You also assign result to new variable.

Comment: @Sayse: I think the sentence is an example input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another `for` loop to iterate over every string in `mylist`.

```
mylist = ['test copy', 'test project', 'test', 'project']
mystring1 = 'it was a nice test project and I enjoyed it a lot'
mystring2 = 'the example test was difficult'

L = [mystring1, mystring2]
for sentence in L:
    for word in mylist:
        if word in sentence:
            splits = sentence.split(word)
            sentence= splits[0]
            print(sentence)
# it was a nice 
# the example
```

Comment: `for sentence in L:` is missing in your answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most effective way to do this is by first constructing a regex, that tests all the strings concurrently:

```
import re

split_regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in mylist))

for sentence in L:
    first_part = split_regex.split(sentence, 1)[0]
```

This yields:

```
>>> split_regex.split(mystring1, 1)[0]
'it was a nice '
>>> mystring2 = 'the example test was difficult'
>>> split_regex.split(mystring2, 1)[0]
'the example '
```

If the number of possible strings is large, a regex can typically outperform searching each string individually.

You probably also want to `.strip()` the string (remove spaces in the front and end of the string):

```
import re

split_regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in mylist))

for sentence in L:
    first_part = split_regex.split(sentence, 1)[0].strip()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['test copy', 'test project', 'test', 'project']
L = ['it was a nice test project and I enjoyed it a lot','a test copy']
for sentence in L:
    for x in mylist:
        if x in sentence:
            splits = sentence.split(x)
            sentence= splits[0]
            print(sentence)
```

the error says you are trying to check a list in sentence. so you must iterate on elements of list.